# Where can you run GAE application built with "integrated" Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Where can you run GAE application built with "integrated" Datastore? Meaning, those application that were build prior to Google platform making the Datastore a separate service from the "core" GAE service. That is without modifying the project.

Can the current Google App Engine run "legacy" applications?

Answer (score 0):

According to the first question App Engine can use Datastore without problem, what do you mean about "integrated"?

But Apps that use these APIs can only run in App Engine and will need to upgrade to the recommended Google Cloud APIs before migrating to newer App Engine runtimes.

And regarding to the last question App engine still provide support to:

- Python 2.7
- Java 8
- Go 1.11
- PHP 5.5

Comment: Do you mean "legacy" apps can still work?

Comment: It could be possible, but I don't recommend it because those legacy apps will be deprecate in the future, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/long-term-support in this link you can read more about google policy about legacy and support, hope this help

Comment: and this one too https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations